# Ошибка при задаче двумерного не квадратного массива

Tags: c++, матрицы

Xcode на маке. Компилирует, но выдает ошибку (`Threat 1: signal SIGABRT`), если матрица не квадратная.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N=3;
const int M=10;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[N][M];

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            a[i][j]=rand()%2;
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поменяйте местами `M` и `N` в циклах.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте местами `M` и `N` в циклах.

Вы объявляете Ваш массив как `int a[N][M];`, где `N = 3` и `M = 10`.

Вы обращаетесь к массиву с помощью двух индексов `a[i][j]`.

Индекс `i` должен быть в пределах от `0` и до `N`, а `j` – от `0` и до `M`.

В Вашем же варианте Вы выходите за пределы массива.

Comment: Затупил, спасибо)

Comment: @BigBoyJack, Если ответ является верным – нажмите на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было замечено в комментариях, у вас неправильно заданы верхние границы для циклов.

```
int a[N][M];

for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
            ^^^^
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                ^^^^
        a[i][j]=rand()%2;
        cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Должно быть

```
int a[N][M];

for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            ^^^
    for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
                ^^^
        a[i][j]=rand()%2;
        cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Чтобы избежать подобного рода ошибок вы можете в C++ инициализировать и вывести на консоль массив следующим образом, используя цикл на основе диапазон.

```
for ( autp &row : a )
{
    for ( auto &x : row )
    {
        x = rand() % 2;
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Имейте в виду, что функция `rand` определена в заголовке `<cstdlib>`, который следует включить в программу

```
#include <cstdlib>
```